# App crashes when trying to call another onGestureListenerAdapter()

Tags: java, android, here-api

I have created 2 `onTapEvent` listener to add markers of different icons to my map through clicking of different buttons. However, I was only able to add 1 type of marker, the second button(add crowd) will crash my app after i clicked it.

Here is the example of my code for the buttons :

Set Destination:

```
private void initAddDestinationButton() {
m_setDetinationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setDestinationButton);

m_setDetinationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             /*
             * Clear map if previous results are still on map,otherwise proceed to creating
             * route
             */
            if (map != null && m_mapRoute != null) {
                map.removeMapObject(m_mapRoute);
                m_mapRoute = null;
            } else
            {
                 addDestination();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void addDestination() {
    if (destinationMarker == null) {
        image = new Image();
        try {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.letterx);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    mapFragment.getMapGesture().removeOnGestureListener(addCrowdListener2);
    mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(setDestinationListener2, 1, true);

}
```

Add Crowd :

```
private void initAddCrowdButton() {
m_addCrowdButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCrowdButton);

m_addCrowdButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view2) {

            if (map != null && m_mapRoute != null) {
                map.removeMapObject(m_mapRoute);
                m_mapRoute = null;
            } else
            {
                addCrowd();

            }
        }
    });

}


private void addCrowd() {
    if (blocked == null) {
        image2 = new Image();
        try {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.marker);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    mapFragment.getMapGesture().removeOnGestureListener(setDestinationListener2);
    mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(addCrowdListener2, 10, true);

}
```

Here are the 2 onTapEvent listeners that I declared:

```
private MapGesture.OnGestureListener addCrowdListener2 = new MapGesture.OnGestureListener.OnGestureListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTapEvent(PointF pointF) {

        GeoCoordinate e = map.pixelToGeo(pointF);
        MapMarker b = new MapMarker(e, image2);

        blockList.add(b);
        b.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()));
        map.addMapObject(b);

        blocked = blockList.get(blockList.size() - 1);
        blockedPath = blocked.getCoordinate();
        blockedRoad = RoadElement.getRoadElement(blockedPath, "eng" );

        return super.onTapEvent(pointF);
    }
};

private MapGesture.OnGestureListener setDestinationListener2 = new MapGesture.OnGestureListener.OnGestureListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
        GeoCoordinate endpoint = map.pixelToGeo(pointF);

            MapMarker m = new MapMarker(endpoint,image);

            markerList.add(m);
            m.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()));
            map.addMapObject(m);

            destinationMarker = markerList.get(markerList.size() - 1);

            destination = destinationMarker.getCoordinate();

        return super.onTapEvent(pointF);
    }
};
```

i have declared the buttons inside `OnEngineInitiaizatioCompleted()`. So far, only Set Destination button runs normally. Clicking on Add Crowd will crash my app (clicked on it before and after clicking Set Destination, crash the app upon clicking)

Here is the stack trace from its crash :

```
02-26 22:22:33.907 2233-3776/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
                                                                                          com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
                                                                                           Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
                                                                                              at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                                              at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
```

and

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.here.android.mpa.common.Image.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
at com.here.android.example.basicpositioningsolution.BasicPositioningActivity.addCrowd(BasicPositioningActivity.java:532)
at com.here.android.example.basicpositioningsolution.BasicPositioningActivity.access$1600(BasicPositioningActivity.java:87)
at com.here.android.example.basicpositioningsolution.BasicPositioningActivity$7.onClick(BasicPositioningActivity.java:521)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22295)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6342)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
Suppressed: java.lang.Throwable: HERE SDK Version: 3.6.0.523
    at com.nokia.maps.MapsEngine$l.uncaughtException(MapsEngine.java:377)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1979)
```

Comment: App crash ? Well post the stack Trace too .

Comment: Hi @ADM, I have added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I think your resource R.drawable.marker cannot be rendered by the SDK. What kind of image resource is it? Only bitmap resources are supported.